# Supernatural fantasy about a punk rocker woman and her very religious former schoolmate fighting evil

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, urban-fantasy, rock-music

I think I read this in the 1980s in F&SF or Amazing. This short story is told from the point of view of a woman (probably in her thirties) who is a punk rock (I think) performer. As the story begins, she's contacted by a former friend from high school who went in a different direction - one detail I remember is that he started out in a mainline Protestant denomination, switched to Catholicism to the surprise of his (probably well-off) family but after a few years converted back to Protestantism, which relieved his family until they learned he was now a radical evangelical or Pentecostal. The story involves the two of them dealing with some supernatural threat that is menacing bars (or one particular bar/club) where she plays.